# Where does os.remove go?

Tags: python

I've been using Python for a long time and have numerous scripts running all over my office. I use a few in particular scripts to back up then delete data. In these script I use `os.remove` function.

My question is: **Where does the os.remove function delete items to?**

- Does it delete them right off the HD?
- I know they don't go to the recycle bin
- Does it simply remove the item's link, but keep it on the HD somehow?

Comment: Where else other than on the filesystem?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

`os.remove`
will call the operating system's `unlink` functionality, and delete the file from the disk.

Technically the OS/filesystem probably just marks the sectors as free, and removes the file entry from the directory, but that's up to the filesystem implementation.

Comment: +1 This is the right answer. Python does not try to do the file system's job, for good reasons.

Comment: Awesome, thanks for the info! And I did mean os.remove, just has delete in my head.

Comment: It does not fully remove and make the sector free. I ran out of disc space and don't know what to do!

Comment: @DragonKnight As I said - it's up to the operating system how unlink is implemented, python just calls the operating system. Dealing with running out of space isn't really a stackoverflow question, and certainly not related to this one.

Comment: @DouglasLeeder You are right. However I was using mac and I had to Turn off and turn on the machine. Restart did not help.

Answer (score 4):

it just deletes them from the harddrive

Comment: In the same way a systems "delete" or "unlink" command does. That *usually* means that the data is not physically scraped from the HDD, but just no longer referenced and there's no "proper" way to get to it. You might be able to "undelete" it if you act before too much is written to the disk, but that's exactly the same is if you delete a file in Explorer (*without* using the trash bin of course).