# Recovering a file deleted with python

Tags: python, operating-system

So, I deleted a file using python. I can't find it in my recycling bin. Is there a way I can `undo` it or something. Thanks in advance.

EDIT: I used `os.remove`. I have tried Recuva, but it doesn't seem to find anything. I have done a deep search.

Comment: Short answer: not easily. Long answer: probably, possibly.

Comment: See [Recuva](http://www.piriform.com/recuva) for example.

Comment: The recycling bin in something windows uses when you delete from the GUI. Using Python, you're not in Kansas any more.

Comment: https://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-list/2007-February/419077.html

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12094663/where-does-os-remove-go It uses the os's unlink. so can't recover that file.

Comment: @RaviKumar Deleted my comment since OP also edited his question. Thanks for pointing that out, though.

Comment: First step remove the drive from box and don't boot from it again.  Your file is still there, but anything you do on it can easily overwrite it now because the spot it was in is no longer allocated to your file.  Step 2 install the drive on another machine with drive recovery software pre installed like http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/PhotoRec.  Step 3 learn to use the software and get your data back.

Comment: @litepresence The file isn't an image.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you used `os.remove` and ended up deleting a file by accident, then there's no reason for this file to be in the recycle bin. It is removed from the filesystem. There is no Python operation to get that file back.

However, a simple deletion just breaks the link to the file but does not erase the bits of the file on the filesystem. You can try file recovery softwares to get it back.

Note that

- Now that the file is erased, this question is not Python specific anymore. You'd be in the same situation if you had deleted the file by any other means.
- You should avoid using your system to minimize the chances of erasing the bits of the file by writing another file at the same place on the disk.
- The tools you can use to recover the file are platform specific and the generic question "how to recover deleted files" has most certainly already been asked here, on Super User, Unix & Linux, or some other Stack Exchange community.

Answer (score 2):

If you deleted the file using PyCharm IDE then it is [possible](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/local-history.html#restore-files-from-local-history). It says:

### Restore deleted files

If you've accidentally deleted a file that was not under version control, you can restore it with Local History.

1. Select the node that contained the file you deleted in the **Project** tool window, right-click it and choose **Local History | Show History** from the context menu.
2. On the left, select the revision that contains the file you want to restore, right-click that file, and choose **Revert Selection**.