# How to restore files that are deleted by os.remove function in python?

Tags: python, restore, python-os

I am just writing a python code to delete files older than 30 days. While running it, Unfortunately, I gave the wrong path and some of my precious data was deleted.

Can you please tell me how can I restore that data?

This is the function that I used

```
def remove_file(path):

    # removing the file
    if not os.remove(path):

        # success message
        print(f"{path} is removed successfully")

    else:

        # failure message
        print(f"Unable to delete the {path}")
```

Comment: What OS are you using?

Comment: I am using Windows OS

Comment: Sorry to admit, but they are gone. There is no trash-bin. You may be lucky with some rescuesystems (There are some Linux live distros).

Comment: This has been asked before
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43419146/recovering-a-file-deleted-with-python#43419284

Comment: Thanks, everyone for your answers, I upvoted you all.

Comment: May be you could use a Windows file recovery program, something like Recuva., but there are other ones You must do it as soon as possible and try not use you the disk on witch you erased data was.

Comment: I tried Recuva but it is not working

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are python modules that allow safe deletion like 'send2trash'. You could then recover the files from the recycle bin or trash