# How to fully remove a file from disc on mac with python?

Tags: python, macos, delete-file

I am using `os.remove(FILE_PATH)` which deletes a file from directory on mac, however, I ran out of disc space because files are not fully removed and I cannot see where they are.

In the question below, it said it makes the sector free but it seems it does not.
[Where does os.remove go?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12094663/where-does-os-remove-go)

Comment: `os.remove` doesn't work on directories. Can you show how exactly have you removed those files?

Comment: @PiotrPraszmo I corrected the questions. `os.remove('./videos/myvideo.mp4')`

Answer (score 0):

I had to turn off my machine and turn it on. Restart didn't work. Any better solution is appreciated.